# Appium's implicitlyWait does not work

Tags: java, ios, selenium, appium

I am using Appium to automate an iOS app but met a problem, is there anyone meet the same problem before?

Appium's `implicitlyWait` API seems to not work. I am using Java and JUnit to run the test, here is the line of code:

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

I have checked the debug info in the appium console, it looks correctly:

> info: [debug] Set iOS implicit wait to 50000ms

**My Environment:**

Latest Appium 1.2.1, Java client library 1.6.1, Selenium Java language binding 2.42.2 and sample app 'UICatalog'provided by Sauce Lab.

Thanks in advance for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted manages the timeout to wait for a maximum of 50 seconds. It doesn't make the driver wait 50 seconds. You can use the wait like:

```
 driver.wait(); //this will wait a max of 50 seconds cuz you said so
```

If you ask me the proper way you would want to use waiting on Webdriver is:

```
WebDriverWait wait;
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("blabla"));
```

The code above checks if blabla is clickable until that condition is proved or 60 seconds(stated above) passes the driver waits.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I have tried to use driver.wait() after set implicit wait but the test is still running without stop. I understand the way you mentioned to use an explicit wait, it works fine. But what if I can't locate the elementToBeClickable? Looking forward to your reply

Answer (score 0):

In Appium it is possible to set implicit way in this way:

Java code:

```
AppiumFieldDecorator decorator = new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver);
decorator.resetImplicitlyWaitTimeOut(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
PageFactory.initElements(decorator, this /* refers to current page object class*/);
```

Such timeout will work for the whole time.

It is not possible (at least I don't know) to change it.

As when web drivers are used you can do this with:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// some actions for which you don't want to wait implicitly
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void WaitForElementPresent1(String locator, int timeout)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    try{   
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(locator)));
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PageFactory model, you can specify the implicit wait with initElements() method as given below -

```
PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);
```

I have tried this with Appium 1.6 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The new way of setting  the implicit time out is using the code

```
AppiumFieldDecorator decorator = new AppiumFieldDecorator(mobDriver);
decorator.DEFAULT_IMPLICITLY_WAIT_TIMEOUT = longValue;
decorator.DEFAULT_TIMEUNIT = TimeUnit.TimeUnit ;
```

Hope this helps